# C# DataTable.Select() - How do I format the filter criteria?

Tags: c#, datatable

this doesn't work

```
DataRow[] mySelectedRows = myDataTable.Select("processed <> True");
```

myDataTable has a row named processed.  I would like to select the rows from this table where processed is not equal to True.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is processed a bool or a string?

If a bool then "not processed" should work otherwise if its a string "processed <> 'True'" - using single quotes as the delimiters within the where string. It would be worth checking the values in the table/column at the point at which you're querying the data to make sure you're testing against the right thing (this has bitten me in the past).

Comment: For reference, which of the two possibilies was the right one?

Comment: sorry for the HUGE delay in my response Murph.  It was a string so processed <> 'True' did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

This should work just fine, but it will not return rows where `processed` is `null`.

To include nulls, try this:

```
DataRow[] rows = myDataTable.Select("isnull(processed, false) <> true");
```

SQL null is an indeterminate value. It does not equal the boolean value `true`, but it does not *not equal* true either. (See [Null (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_null#Common_mistakes).)

For the general filter expression reference, see [the `DataColumn.Expression` MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(VS.71).aspx).